# PayPal Not Passing Amount For Donation

Tags: paypal

I'm building a website for a client that has to take donations. I want to have the donation value passed through and automatically filled when they land on PayPal. I have two different sets of code with two different errors.

I do not have access to my clients PayPal account so please let me know if it's not solvable on my end. I do have their merchant ID, which has been redacted in the below code with "merchantidgoeshere".

**Code 1: Goes To Merchant Donation Form But Doesn't Pass The Value**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="merchantidnumberhere" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation Description">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">

    <br /><input name="submit" type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_donate_92x26.png" /><span class="lazy_container" style="width: 1px;"><span class="lazy_preloader" style="padding-top: 100%;"></span><img width="1" height="1" alt="" src="plugins/system/tmlazyload/blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" border="0" /></span>
</form>
```

**Code 2: Doesn't Go To Page And Redirects To Error Page With The Message:**
*We cannot process this transaction because there is a problem with the PayPal email address supplied by the seller. Please contact the seller to resolve the problem. If this payment is for an eBay listing, you can contact the seller via the "Ask Seller a Question" link on the listing page. When you have the correct email address, payment can be made at www.paypal.com.*

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="merchantidnumberhere" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation Description">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">

    <br /><input name="submit" type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_donate_92x26.png" /><span class="lazy_container" style="width: 1px;"><span class="lazy_preloader" style="padding-top: 100%;"></span><img width="1" height="1" alt="" src="plugins/system/tmlazyload/blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" border="0" /></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first button is a hosted button, so the amount details would have to be set at in the button wizard within the PayPal account.  You won't be able to pass your own dynamic value using a hosted button.

The second one is working fine for me when I replace "merchantidnumberhere" with a valid account email address.  Did you make sure to update the business parameter with a valid email address or account ID?

Comment: So the second option is the one I want since it needs to be a dynamic value. I am certain the merchant id number is correct because it's the same merchant ID that works in the first example which does navigate to the merchants donation page.

Comment: Again, the first example is a hosted button, so the fields you add there are essentially ignored. The error from the second one specifically tells you there is a problem with the email address passed, and again, it works perfectly fine when I put my own seller account ID in there.  You may be certain, but check again.  ;)

Comment: Hi Andrew, you were right the second code snippet works. I was indeed using the right merchant id so I'm not sure why it didn't work. When I just used the e-mail address it worked fine. If you have thoughts on that, would love to hear it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note, to force English as the language the code shouldn't be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
```

It should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="en_US">
```

Cheers from Spain!